# Strange MSCV (Visual C++) optimization issue -- optimized (?) code runs slower

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-c++

I have the piece of code as below. It performs a simple paint with alpha channel mask. The obvious way of optimizing it is to skip all the pixels that have alpha value of zero. I have tested this on real-life images where zeros make around 40% of the alpha values, I have created tests with synthetic images where 50% of the alpha values were zero... and the results surprised me. The code with "if (a)" runs slower (30-40% slower!) than without it. I did generate assembly code and there is nothing extraordinary, no large block operations, nothing. I run it on Intel i9 under Windows 10, code runs as 32bit, are release build (with speed optimization enabled).

I have added separate code that can be compiled separately with test data created (half of the alpha channel data should be zero). And the outcome is the same, commenting out "if (a)" makes the program run faster about 20%.

Is there any explanation why is this happening?

```
  BYTE* pSrc, * pDest;
  const int nBottom = min(rSrcRect.Height(), pDibDest->Height() - rDestRect.top);
  const int nRight = min(rSrcRect.Width(), pDibDest->Width() - rDestRect.left);
  for (int y = 0; y < nBottom; y++)
  {
    pSrc = pDibSrc->GetPixel(rSrcRect.left, rSrcRect.top + y);
    pDest = pDibDest->GetPixel(rDestRect.left, rDestRect.top + y);
    for (int x = 0; x < nRight; x++)
    {
      int a = pSrc[x * nSrcAlign + 3];
// The following "optimization" is actually making the code run slower
      if (a)
//
      {
        int _a = 255 - a;
        pDest[0 + x * nDestAlign] = ((int)pDest[0 + x * nDestAlign] * _a + (int)pSrc[0 + x * nSrcAlign] * a + 127) / 255;
        pDest[1 + x * nDestAlign] = ((int)pDest[1 + x * nDestAlign] * _a + (int)pSrc[1 + x * nSrcAlign] * a + 127) / 255;
        pDest[2 + x * nDestAlign] = ((int)pDest[2 + x * nDestAlign] * _a + (int)pSrc[2 + x * nSrcAlign] * a + 127) / 255;
      }
    }
  }
```

Standalone code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void OptText(unsigned char *pA, unsigned char *pB, int startx, int w, int h, int linewa, int linewb)
{
  const int nSrcAlign = 4;
  const int nDestAlign = 3;
  unsigned char* pSrc, * pDest;
  for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
  {
    pSrc = pA + startx * nSrcAlign + y * linewa;
    pDest = pB + y * linewb;
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
      int a = pSrc[x * nSrcAlign + 3];
      //if (a)
      {
        int _a = 255 - a;
        pDest[0 + x * nDestAlign] = ((int)pDest[0 + x * nDestAlign] * _a + (int)pSrc[0 + x * nSrcAlign] * a + 127) / 255;
        pDest[1 + x * nDestAlign] = ((int)pDest[1 + x * nDestAlign] * _a + (int)pSrc[1 + x * nSrcAlign] * a + 127) / 255;
        pDest[2 + x * nDestAlign] = ((int)pDest[2 + x * nDestAlign] * _a + (int)pSrc[2 + x * nSrcAlign] * a + 127) / 255;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int maxw = 2048;
  int maxh = 2048;
  int linewa = maxw * 4;
  int linewb = maxh * 3;
  unsigned char* pTestData1 = new unsigned char[maxw * maxh * 4];
  unsigned char* pTestData2 = new unsigned char[maxw * maxh * 3];
  srand(10000);
  for (int i = 0; i < maxw * maxh * 4; i++)
  {
    if (i % 4 == 3)
      pTestData1[i] = rand() % 2;
    else
      pTestData1[i] = rand() % 256;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < maxw * maxh * 3; i++)
    pTestData2[i] = rand() % 256;

  int t1 = GetTickCount();
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    int startx = rand() % (maxw / 2);
    unsigned char *pA = pTestData1 + rand() % (maxh / 2) * linewa;
    unsigned char* pB = pTestData2 + rand() % (maxh / 2) * linewb;
    int w = rand() % (maxw / 2);
    int h = rand() % (maxh / 2);
    OptText(pA, pB, startx, w, h, linewa, linewb);
  }

  int t2 = GetTickCount();
  printf("Run %d msec\n", t2 - t1);
}
```

Comment: Conditional branches can defeat branch prediction and be costly. Anyway, I don't see how this could balance the cost of all the arithmetic that can be spared.

Comment: Try profiling both version of the code.

Comment: Are you compiling with compiler optimizations enabled ?

Comment: Yes, I am testing on optimized for speed release build.

Comment: Are you mixing languages?  The `new` operator is not valid C language.  Your posted code is C++.

Comment: You can speed things up by using constant temporary variables for repeated calculations.  For example: `x * nDestAlign` is used multiple places.  Although the compiler *may* optimize this repeated expression, you can always help out the compiler. :-)